# Having multiple perspectives open at the same time in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, perspective

I have a large screen and would like to show **Package Explorer** and **Console** (in **Java** and **Debug** perspectives respectively) in Eclipse at the same time.

I don't want to click on "Java" or "Debug" icon or select "Window --> show perspective --> ..." each time I want to switch between perspectives or see them.

Any ideas?

Comment: try adding those two views to both perspectives.

Comment: How can we change the views in a perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite possible as you describe in your question (each eclipse workbench only supports displaying one perspective), but the following options will give you a similar effect:

1. Open multiple eclipse windows, each using a different perspective. This isn't a great option though, which leads to...
2. (**Recommended**) - avoid perspectives entirely, and just open up all the relevant **views**, positioning them where you want.

I use option 2 myself - everything is open at the same time, and since you don't have things shuffling around or disappearing when you switch "perspectives", it's easy to train yourself to remember where specific views are.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply `Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective...`
This will help to add needed functional to toolbar and/or menu if it's impossible to use as a perspective window

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple perspectives in two windows connected to same workspace instance. Choose: **Window -> New Window**. Then another window gets opened. Let the new and old windows be side by side. Now you can open another perspective in this new window. And you can for example, also debug, and both windows will have same values for variables during debug.